# Latex document background looks grey

Tags: formatting, mac

I recently updated my macbook to the 'Mojave' OS and activated dark mode, and while I generally appreciate the reduced brightness it appears to have caused my latex document backgrounds to become grey instead of white as seen below:

[image]

The photo actually has a sample google page on the right side, but it matches the tex background perfectly; the spacing was to avoid the 'shading' effect between pages.

I didn't change my preamble at all, this simply happened when I updated to mojave and selected dark mode.  Does anyone know of a fix?

In response to JouleV's comment below, here is a picture with the brightness all the way up:

[image]

The latex document is in the top left with a default google page in the top right again.

Comment: @JouleV Even with my brightness set to maximum the issue persists, and this did not happen prior to the update -- I'll upload a pic with brightness at max.  Where would this post be on topic if not here?

Comment: @PeterGrill Your latter suggestion worked perfectly, thank you.  If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: If you print the document is the background gray? It might just be that your previewer is adding that in dark mode. Some applications allow you to change the background color of that display.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want the gray background, you can disable dark mode, or use `\pagecolor{white}` (which requires that the `xcolor` package be loaded).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{white}

\begin{document}
    Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer does not describe how to use this command, nor does it explain that you have to import a package.

Comment: @FinncentPrice: Thanks for pointing that out. Has been corrected.

Answer (score 13):

Another option that does not require changing the actual LaTeX documents appears to be adjusting the TeXShop theme.
If you head to the settings and adjust the color highlighted in the screenshot from grey to white, you should be able to get the white background as desired.

[image: TeXShop preference window screenshot with the mentioned setting highlighted]